# LaTeX complaining about illegal parameter number

Tags: latex3, expl3

Inspired by [a question yesterday](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96399/how-can-i-illustrate-decimal-to-binary-conversion), I thought I'd try my hand at a LaTeX3 solution which would **show** how to convert base 10 numbers into any other base of the user's choice.

Yesterday I wrote a nice simple version that worked.  But today, I decided I wanted to separate the building of the steps from the process of outputting and formatting those steps.  I also thought it would be interesting to explore the possibilities of creating the effect of *an array within an array* using `sequences` and `token lists`.

But now, I'm getting an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xparse}
\pagestyle{empty}
\ExplSyntaxOn
%% setting and getting the base
\int_new:N \g__new_base_int
\NewDocumentCommand{\setbase}{ m }{
    \int_gset:Nn \g__new_base_int { #1 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\getbase}{}{
    \int_use:N \g__new_base_int
}
%% setting and getting the number to be converted
\int_new:N \g__number_to_convert_int
\NewDocumentCommand{\setnumber}{ m }{
    \int_gset:Nn \g__number_to_convert_int {#1}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\getnumber}{ }{
    \int_use:N \g__number_to_convert_int
}

%%---internal function to build each step in the conversion process
%%---and the parameters to be used for this function
\int_new:N \l__quotient_int
\int_new:N \l__tmp_new_quotient_int
\int_new:N \l__remainder_int
\seq_new:N \g__steps_of_conversion
\cs_new:Nn \__build_steps_of_conversion: {
    \int_set_eq:NN \l__quotient_int  \g__number_to_convert_int
    \int_do_while:nn { \l__quotient_int >= \g__new_base_int }
        {
            \int_set:Nn \l__remainder_int {  \int_mod:nn { \l__quotient_int } { \g__new_base_int } }
            \int_set:Nn \l__tmp_new_quotient_int { \int_div_truncate:nn { \l__quotient_int } {\g__new_base_int }}
            \exp_args:NNx \seq_gput_right:Nn \g__steps_of_conversion 
                {  
                    {\int_use:N \g__new_base_int  }
                    {\int_use:N \l__quotient_int  }
                    {\int_use:N \l__remainder_int }
                    {\int_use:N \l__tmp_new_quotient_int}
                }
            \int_set_eq:NN \l__quotient_int \l__tmp_new_quotient_int
        }
}
%%---internal function to construct the display of the conversion process
\bool_new:N \l__first_item_on_line_bool
\cs_new:Nn \__show_steps_of_conversion: {
    \__build_steps_of_conversion:
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \g__steps_of_conversion 
        {
            \bool_set_true:N \l__first_item_on_line_bool
            \tl_map_inline:nn { ##1 } {
                \bool_if:NF \l__first_item_on_line_bool { & }
                ###1 
                \bool_set_false:N \l__first_item_on_line_bool
            }
            \\
        }
}
%%---user interface to displaying the conversion
\NewDocumentCommand{\showstepsofconversion}{ o }{
    \[
        \begin{array}{crc|r}
            \text{Base} & & \text{R} & \text{Q} \\\hline
            \__show_steps_of_conversion: 
        \end{array}
    \]
}
%% accessing and using LaTeX3's internal base conversion
\NewDocumentCommand{\converttobase}{m}{
    \int_to_base:nn {#1} \g__new_base_int
}
%%
\ExplSyntaxOff
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setbase{21}
\setnumber{2680010}
\begin{document}

The base is \getbase.  \getnumber{} becomes $\converttobase{\getnumber}_{\getbase}$.

\showstepsofconversion

\end{document}
```

The problem seems to be `###1`.  Oddly, the output is as I desire.  The suggested correction to `##1` is clearly not correct and when I rewrite my code to `##1` I get the wrong value.

Comment: `#` must be doubled, so I guess you need `####1`.

Comment: @egreg.  That works.  Thanks.  But it also seem peculiar and counter-intuitive to how LaTeX usually works.  Why the need for the doubling?

Comment: Not related to the issue at hand, but `expl3` code should always be set up in a defined namespace. So here you might have `\showbaseconv_...` as the function prefix, and therefore `\l_showbaseconv_...` for a local variable, _etc._

Comment: @A.Ellett No, it's entirely how TeX works: each time you nest a level of definitions, you have to double up each `#`.

Comment: @JosephWright.  True, true.  Thanks for reminding me about the convensions.  I keep slipping on them.

Comment: When a replacement text for a macro contains `#1` TeX substitutes the first argument; when it contains `##` it substitutes `#`. (This is not the complete truth, but a good approximation.)

Comment: Then I guess I've misunderstood the TeX approach (probably because I usually never really nested things too much).  Good to learn.

Comment: Should I change the title to reflect this?  Something like `###1 not parsing correctly`

Comment: there are several questions on doubling `#` already eg http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71632/why-do-paramaters-of-renewcommand-need-to-double-up-the-within-a-foreach/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Perhaps we need a canonical question on this ([tag:tex-core]?) to link to

Comment: @josephwright.  This whole matter of *namespaces* seems to result in unyieldy, long names.  It seems like LaTeX3 could do with a healthy dose of encapsulation capabilities.  Can you direct me to sources that will explain the choice for the current format?

Comment: @A.Ellett Well the 'rules' are laid out in the [`expl3` concepts guide](http://texdoc.net/pkg/expl3). The bottom line is TeX does not have a namespace system (and even if it did you'd still need to manage the module names). The formalised approach in `expl3` is pretty much the same as good practice for LaTeX2e packages, where many packages use `\foo@...` in names. If you want more on this, probably best to ask on in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) or on LaTeX-L as it's likely to be a discussion.

Comment: I *misconstrued* my problem to be a LaTeX3 problem.  It seems now from the feedback you all have given me that this is really a duplicate of the answer to the  question [Why do paramaters of \renewcommand need to double up the # within a \foreach](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71633/22413)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you want 4 `#` to refer to `#1` in a macro definition. (This is primitive TeX parsing, not a LaTeX3 feature)

```
            ####1
```

not

```
            ###1
```