# How do I write 'decimal to Binary convertion ' in Latex?

Tags: tables, math-mode

[image: ****]

How can I make like this...plz help!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please post the code which you have tried so far and where are you struck exactly. As of now, this is a do it for me kind of question.

Comment: You can also try looking arround: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/repeated-division-converting-from-base-10-to-another-base/114005#114005

Comment: BTW, that is decimal to octal conversion.  Binary would be 100110111.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96399/how-can-i-illustrate-decimal-to-binary-conversion help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \displayasdecimal#1 {(#1) \sb {10}}
\cs_new:Npn \displayasoctal #1 {(\int_to_oct:n{#1}) \sb 8}
\cs_new:Npn \displayasbinary #1 {(\int_to_bin:n{#1}) \sb 2}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\displayasdecimal{311}=\displayasoctal{311}=\displayasbinary{311}$

\end{document}
```

This gets you

[image]

If you actually want to do the calculation automatically and dislay it as in the top of your picture then that would be possible too using `expl3`.

Comment: Not sure if the OP was looking for the actual conversion or the graphical algorithm, but this is a good answer anyway :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B maybe not, but then he/she should put a bit more effort in the question. And in fact, egreg's pointer gets you to an example to calculate and display

Comment: :-) I fully agree.